# Angular Material Trigger Touched State Programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Angular 4 Reactive Forms with `@angular/material` version `2.0.0-beta.10`. I need to programmatically make the `md-error` message appear.

On required fields, when a user leaves an input without entering any text, I have an `md-error` that says, "This field is required." See code:

```
<md-form-field>
    <input mdInput type="text"
           formControlName="PartNumber"
           placeholder="Part Number"
           maxlength="250"
           required />
    <md-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls['PartNumber'].hasError('required')">
        Part Number is <strong>required</strong>
    </md-error>
</md-form-field>
```

I've tried both:

```
this.formGroup.markAsTouched();
this.formGroup.markAsDirty();
```

The `md-error` text underneath the `<input>` does not appear when I call `markAsTouched()` or `markAsDirty()`.

How do I programmatically trigger a touched state so that the error message appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to loop through each control and mark each one as touched:

```
Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    const ctrl = this.formGroup.get(key);
    ctrl.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
});
```

Comment: or ctr.markAsDirty() if not working

Answer (score 4):

A better solution may be to use a [custom error matcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher).

Here's an example of using a class property to decide when the error should be shown: http://plnkr.co/edit/U5xtdKWggcbgU2EHKkK9?p=preview

```
<md-form-field>
  <input mdInput [formControl]="myInput" placeholder="My Input" [errorStateMatcher]="showWhenISayTo">
  <md-error>Field is required</md-error>
</md-form-field>


// Set this to `true` to show the errors
showError = false;

myInput = new FormControl('', Validators.required)

showWhenISayTo = () => {
  return this.showError;
}
```

Also, you can configure it to use the same behavior globally. Here's an example of showing errors as soon as the invalid control is dirty: http://plnkr.co/edit/gcQuzYChrl5d7UYXo8eS?p=preview

```
import {MD_ERROR_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, showOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MD_ERROR_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {errorStateMatcher: showOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher}}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just mark the whole formGroup as touched by calling `markAllAsTouched`. No need to loop through and mark every control on its own.

```js
this.formGroup.markAllAsTouched();
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAllAsTouched

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Targaryen, this approach is only valid for Angular 8+

Comment: That feature was not available until Angular Material version 8, which is outside the scope of this question.